# Issues while configuring the API Subscription BPS WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process

So, i've my WSO2 BPS 3.6.0 configured to support SSL and a custom hostname i.e. **mydomain.domain.com:9445** etc. and i'm trying to implement the **API Subscription Workflow** by following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+API+Subscription+Workflow) documentation.

Now i've performed the following steps:

- set the offset of wso2 bps to 2 and it is running fine with port: 9445
- edited the **wsa:Address** tag in both**SubscriptionService.epr** and **SubscriptionCallbackService.epr** located in API-M_HOME/business-processes/epr
  as the bps server had a customized hostname instead of localhost (not sure if performing this step was right)

  SubscriptionService.epr 
  [image]
  SubscriptionCallBackService.epr
  [image]
- copy-pasted the epr folder from API-M_HOME/business-processes/epr to BPS_HOME/repository/conf/epr
- Added the required **BPEL package** and **human task** accordingly
- Navigated to the carbon console from APIM and edited the **workflow-extensions.xml**, here's how it looks like 
  [image]
- set the **TaskCoordinationEnabled** tag of **b4p-cordination-config.xml** to **true** located in BPS_Home\repository\conf

Consider OTHER required configurations:

**At API Manager End**:

- site.json file located at APIM_Home\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\admin\site\conf

> ```
> {
>   "theme": {
>     "base": "wso2",
>     "subtheme": "modern"
>   },
>   "context": "/admin",
>   "request_url": "READ_FROM_REQUEST",
>   "tasksPerPage": 10,
>   "allowedPermission": "/permission/admin/manage/apim_admin",
>   "workflows": {
>      "workFlowServerURL": "https://mydomain.domain.com:9445/services/",
>   },
>   "ssoConfiguration": {
>     "enabled": "false",
>     "issuer": "API_WORKFLOW_ADMIN",
>     "identityProviderURL": "https://localhost:9443/samlsso",
>     "keyStorePassword": "",
>     "identityAlias": "",
>     "keyStoreName": "",
>     "verifyAssertionValidityPeriod": "true",
>     "audienceRestrictionsEnabled": "true",
>     "responseSigningEnabled": "true",
>     "assertionSigningEnabled": "true",
>     "assertionEncryptionEnabled": "false",
>     "idpInit" : "false",
>     "idpInitSSOURL" : "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?spEntityID=API_WORKFLOW_ADMIN",
>     "externalLogoutPage" : "https://localhost:9443/samlsso?slo=true"
>   },
>   "reverseProxy": {
>     "enabled": false,
>     // values true , false , "auto" - will look for  X-Forwarded-* headers
>     "host": "sample.proxydomain.com",
>     // If reverse proxy do not have a domain name use IP
>     "context": ""
>     //"regContext":"" // Use only if different path is used for registry
>   }
> }
> ```

- the workflowconfiguration in api-manager.xml
  [image]

**At BPS end**:

- carbon.xml 
  [image]

**Issue:** Now whenever a user navigates to APIM Store and subscribes to any API, the subscription request is listed at the APIM Admin console. When i select APPROVE from the provided ddl and click on the COMPLETE button, the record vanishes. However, this is the error that i see at WSO2's CMD windows:

**APIM's cmd window**

> [2017-11-09 00:13:17,022]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will
>   expire all cal lbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective
>   of the timeout action, af ter the specified or optional timeout
>
> [2017-11-09 00:13:17,164] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: Host name
>   verificatio n failed for host : localhost javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   Host name verification failed for host : localhost
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(C
>   lientSSLSetupHandler.java:171)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession
>   .java:308)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSes
>   sion.java:410)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(Abstra
>   ctIODispatch.java:119)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor
>   .java:159)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(Abstr
>   actIOReactor.java:338)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(Abst
>   ractIOReactor.java:316)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIO
>   Reactor.java:277)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.
>   java:105)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.
>   run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> [2017-11-09 00:13:17,188]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint w
>   ith address
>   https://localhost:9443/store/site/blocks/workflow/workflow-listener/
>   ajax/workflow-listener.jag will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
>
> [2017-11-09 00:13:17,193]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint
>   : Anonymou sEndpoint with address
>   https://localhost:9443/store/site/blocks/workflow/workflo
>   w-listener/ajax/workflow-listener.jag - current suspend duration is :
>   30000ms - Next retry after : Thu Nov 09 00:13:47 EST 2017
>
> [2017-11-0900:13:17,201]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' 
>   sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101500, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender
>
> [2017-11-09 00:14:17,238]  INFO - SourceHandler Writer null when
>   calling informW riterError [2017-11-09 00:14:17,238]  WARN -
>   SourceHandler Connection time out after reques t is read:
>   http-incoming-1 Socket Timeout : 60000 Remote Address : /10.10.30.130
>   :49249
>
> [2017-11-09 00:14:24,671] ERROR - AxisEngine The endpoint
>   reference (EPR) for th e Operation not found is
>   /services/WorkflowCallbackService and the WSA Action = null. If this
>   EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administra
>   tor. org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the
>   Operation not f ound is /services/WorkflowCallbackService and the WSA
>   Action = null. If this EPR  was previously reachable, please contact
>   the server administrator.
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPha
>   se.java:102)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEn
>   closingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.j
>   ava:158)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
>   WorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [2017-11-09 00:14:24,673] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing GET request for :
>   /services/WorkflowCallbackService org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The
>   endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not f ound is
>   /services/WorkflowCallbackService and the WSA Action = null. If this
>   EPR  was previously reachable, please contact the server
>   administrator.
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPha
>   se.java:102)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:329)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEn
>   closingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.j
>   ava:158)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
>   WorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**BPS's cmd window:**

> [2017-11-09 00:14:16,738] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.Partn erService} -  Error
>   sending message to Axis2 for ODE mex {PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhc
>   nphrcr2a32g83oh [PID
>   {http://workflow.subscription.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org}Subscr
>   iptionApprovalWorkFlowProcess-1] calling
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@705 fc38f.resumeEvent(...) Status
>   REQUEST} org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out
>           at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.jav
>   a:199)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessa
>   geWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(Com
>   monsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
>           at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(O
>   utOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
>           at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
>   149)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.utils.AxisServiceUtils.invo
>   keService(AxisServiceUtils.java:323)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.PartnerService.invoke(Partn
>   erService.java:333)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELMessageExchangeContextI
>   mpl.invokePartner(BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.java:43)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.invoke(BpelRuntimeC
>   ontextImpl.java:897)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.INVOKE.run(INVOKE.java:130)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.run(JacobVPU.java:4
>   51)
>           at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU.execute(JacobVPU.java:139)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.execute(BpelRuntime
>   ContextImpl.java:1002)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.invokeInstance(Partn
>   erLinkMyRoleImpl.java:250)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$1.invoke(BpelProcess.java:288)
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java
> ```
>
> :224)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java
>   :279)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.handleJobDetails(BpelProcess.j
>   ava:434)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelEngineIm
>   pl.java:558)
>           at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelServerIm
>   pl.java:467)
>           at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleS
>   cheduler.java:633)
>           at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleS
>   cheduler.java:627)
>           at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(Simpl
>   eScheduler.java:298)
>           at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(Simpl
>   eScheduler.java:253)
>           at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleSch
>   eduler.java:627)
>           at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleSch
>   eduler.java:611)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:918)
>
> ```
>     at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
>     at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:
> ```
>
> 78)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106
>   )
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.
>   java:1116)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$Http
>   ConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMetho
>   dBase.java:1973)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodB
>   ase.java:1735)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.j
>   ava:1098)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Htt
>   pMethodDirector.java:398)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMe
>   thodDirector.java:171)
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
>   a:397)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(Abst
>   ractHTTPSender.java:659)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.jav
>   a:195)
>           ... 34 more

What could be the issue here? Any idea? do let me know. Thanks

**Note that the bps workflow for API STATE CHANGE works just fine with the same configurations**

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that you are using calls with HTTPS with specific domain names

> Host name verification failed for host : localhost at  org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:171) at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession .java:308)

the certificate provided is `CN=localhost`, so indeed the host verification fails

what you can do about it

- simplest way is switching to **http** when on secure network (behind firewall, vpn, ..)
- update SSL certificates of BPS and APIM to match their hostnames and they have to trust each others certificate (or certificate issuer)
- disable SSL hostname validation in axis2.xml (I do not recommend it, good for DEV, VERY BAD for PROD) - set `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>`

Comment: thank you for answering! @gusto2 in my case, the certificates + hostname for APIM and BPS are SAME! what other configurations are required?

Comment: Apparently from your previous questions you have only basic notion of using the certificates. It is important to know that the CN **must** match the hostname (so CN=localhost will work only on localhost). So you either get or create valid certificates and [configure the ssl](https://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/) or use http if feasible. You can still disable the hostname validation when accepting the risk

Comment: Right. Can you please specify the risks that i may encounter by disabling the hostname validation?

Comment: when using pure http you communicate plaintext (no encryption) and you are aware of it (can be ok on backend networks). Disabling hostname validation will still use SSL, however someone using trusted certificate from other site would be able to spoof the comminucation and you would not be aware of it. When building PoC or DEV environment, feel free to disable the hostname validation, for production accessing the servers from internet you should be careful

Comment: okay. i edited the axis2.xml of apim for disabling hostname validation in the class=org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender
 section but the issue still persists.

Comment: and.. do it on BPS too, check if there are multiple senders that need the parameter update